# Syncing data fetched from retrofit (MutableLiveData) with data from Room DB (LiveData) in an android app

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, android-room

The basic idea of the app is the following: fetch data from server using retrofit whenever its up, fall back on local room database whenever the server is unreachable. I have an issue with the way I'm saving data in my view models however. I'm using `LiveData` for the data fetched from Room and `MutableLiveData` for the data fetched from the server. Not sure how to have a single source for the data though. The Retrofit API returns my entities (`Recipe`) as `List<Recipe>`. Only way I know to persist that is using `MutableLiveData`:

```
var readAllIngredients = MutableLiveData<List<Ingredient>>().apply { value = emptyList() }
...
readAllIngredients.postValue(NetworkService.service.getIngredients())
```

Changing `readAllIngredients` to `LiveData<List<Ingredient>>` and then trying to set the `value` field of the list doesn't work since apparently `value` is not assignable to.

Can't make the DAO return `MutableLiveData<List<Ingredient>>` either (getting some compile errors). And I heard trying to cast one of these types to the other isn't exactly best practice. So I'm not sure what else I could try.

```
class InventoryViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    var readAllIngredients = MutableLiveData<List<Ingredient>>().apply { value = emptyList() }
    private val ingredientRepository: IngredientRepository

    init {
        val ingredientDAO = ShoppingAppDatabase.getDatabase(application).ingredientDAO()
        ingredientRepository = IngredientRepository(ingredientDAO)
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // logic moved from repository in order to make example more concise 
            if(NetworkService.serverReachable()) {
                readAllIngredients.postValue(NetworkService.service.getIngredients())
            }
            else {
                //save the data from the database somehow; used to do it like
                //readAllIngredients = ingredientRepository.allIngredients 
                //when readAllIngredients was of type `LiveData<List<Ingredient>>`
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediatorLiveData is used when you want to combine multiple sources. Example:

```
class InventoryViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    var readAllIngredients = MediatorLiveData<List<Ingredient>>().apply { value = emptyList() }
    private val ingredientRepository: IngredientRepository
    private var gotNetworkIngredients = false

    init {
        val ingredientDAO = ShoppingAppDatabase.getDatabase(application).ingredientDAO()
        ingredientRepository = IngredientRepository(ingredientDAO)
        readAllIngredients.addSource(ingredientRepository.allIngredients) { repoValue ->
            if (!gotNetworkIngredients) {
                readAllIngredients.value = repoValue
            }
        }

        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // logic moved from repository in order to make example more concise 
            if(NetworkService.serverReachable()) {
                gotNetworkIngredients = true
                readAllIngredients.postValue(NetworkService.service.getIngredients())
            }
            else {
                //save the data from the database somehow; used to do it like
                //readAllIngredients = ingredientRepository.allIngredients 
                //when readAllIngredients was of type `LiveData<List<Ingredient>>`
            }
        }
    }
}
```